# Boas práticas com controllers AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller

Em uma view responsável pelo cadastro dos membros da entidade `usuarios`, caso seja necessário acessar dados de uma entidade `pessoas`, por exemplo, o ideal é que o método que buscará os dados desta `pessoa` pertença a algo como `UsuariosController` ou `PessoasController`?

No back-end eu buscaria os dados de `PessoasController`, mas, até onde percebi, não é possível acessar métodos de mais de um controller em cada seção da view. Além disso, não me parece fazer sentido um formulário de cadastro de `usuarios` utilizando algo como `ng-controller=PessoasController`.

Me desculpem a inexperiência, mas como vocês fariam?

Answer (score 1):

Ao meu ver, você está com uma bagagem carregada de MVC tradicional do backend.

Se Eu entendi bem você está falando de uma entidade relacional, de banco de dados, no qual *Usuário* tem relação 1-1 com *Pessoa*, estou certo?

Se sim, a ideia neste caso é que você abstraia isso no servidor e a aplicação não precisa de detalhes de implementação do servidor, recebendo um único objeto sem diferenciar duas entidades diferentes.

Mas, para sanar sua dúvida, é possível sim acessar dados de outro controller no AngularJS desde que você acesse através de um **controller filho** o escopo do **controller pai**.

Eu criei um exemplo bem simples no JS Fiddle, usando sua lógica de Pessoa e Usuário, no qual o escopo do usuário está dentro de Pessoa, no link abaixo.

https://jsfiddle.net/luishmcmoreno/e6gj4bcs/

Para facilitar o acesso, foi usado a síntaxe **controller as** para referenciar melhor cada escopo. Podendo acessa-lo via contexto *this* do controller. Caso não saiba como funciona o *controller as*, pesquise na internet que tem boas referências.

Para um estudo mais aprofundado eu sugiro fortemente a leitura do link abaixo, que explica detalhadamente como funciona o $scope no angular.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

A outra maneira de você compartilhar informações entre escopos é usando **factory** ou **service**. O angular é considerado um framework *MVW* ou *MV** por muitos usuários. Justamente por ter mais camadas como *services, factories, filters*, entre outros.

Neste caso, não é necessário em que os escopos sejam *pai e filho*. Esta é a forma mais recomendável de se compartilhar informações entre os controllers, pois, evita reuso de código.

Eu criei outro jsfiddle para demonstrar o compartilhamento de informação entre controllers. Segue abaixo.

https://jsfiddle.net/luishmcmoreno/hs8pdm47/

Só salientar que estes dois exemplos criados foram com propósitos didáticos e não seguem as melhores práticas de angular. Estes exemplos foram criados para que você entenda melhor como funciona o escopo pai e filho e como funcionam o compartilhamento de informação usando outras camadas da aplicação, como service.

Sugiro que pratique bastante. Para seguir as melhores práticas de desenvolvimento com o Angular, leia o excelente guia de estilo do John Papa, traduzido para Português. Porém, aconselho que leia depois que você tenha entendido, pelo menos superficialmente, como funcionam todas as camadas de uma aplicação angular: module, config, resource, run, controller, service, factory, filter.

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/i18n/pt-BR.md

Comment: Perfeito, Luis. Preciso mesmo estudar melhor essas camadas. A abordagem voltada ao MVC back-end é devida a um framework que estou estudando atualmente. Mas, e você, como trataria esse caso? Teria os dois controllers e os utilizaria como no seu exemplo mesmo? Obrigado.

Comment: eu não entendi muito bem qual a real necessidade. Nesse caso eu abstrairia da aplicação as regras de negócio do servidor e, no AngularJS teria um json já embutido todas as informações de usuário e pessoa, sem precisar separá-los em dois controllers. Mas na verdade, eu não entendi a necessidade porque não sei qual é a regra de negócio aplicada. As vezes tenha necessidade de se separar em dois controllers mas acredito que não.

Comment: Trata-se de um formulário de cadastro de usuários. Neste formulário há um campo do tipo select com a lista das pessoas cadastradas no sistema. Eu desejo obter o email da pessoa selecionada e exibi-lo no campo de email no cadastro do usuário. A dúvida em relação ao controller surgiu do fato de eu lidar com duas entidades no mesmo formulário.